# Teradata backup information query

Tags: backup, reporting, teradata

I'm looking for a way to query the last backup time for each database in Teradata 14.10. I am piecing together something with info from DBQL tables, but am unable to get anything that seems to be coherent. Does anyone know of a query to show th most recent backup for each database? Preferrably pulled from DBQL if possible. This is what I am currently using:

```
SELECT A.UserName, A.QueryID, B.SqlTextInfo, A.StatementType, A.LogDate
FROM PDCRINFO.DBQLogTbl_Hst A
INNER JOIN DBQLSqlTbl_Hst B
ON A.QueryID = B.QueryID
WHERE A.UserName = '<ARCMAIN user>'
AND A.LogDate = '<date of backup>'
AND A.StatementType = 'Release Lock'
ORDER BY B.SqlTextInfo ASC;
```